# Ruby: NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

Would anybody have an idea, why following code returns error:

```
stock = {"M9788375085969"=>5, "M9788392289760"=>5, "M9788389371461"=>1, "M9788389371447"=>3, "M9788392289761"=>2}
add = {"M9788375085969"=>1, "M9788392289760"=>2, "NEW9788392289753"=>1 }

add.each do |key, value|
  stock[key] += value
end

NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

while similar thing works fine:

```
key = "M9788375085969"
value = 1
stock[key] += value
=> 6
```

Comment: Seems pretty straight-forward, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key `"NEW9788392289753"` is not present in the Hash `stock`,but present in `add` hash. See below :

```
stock = {"M9788375085969"=>5, "M9788392289760"=>5, "M9788389371461"=>1, "M9788389371447"=>3, "M9788392289761"=>2}
stock['NEW9788392289753'] # => nil
nil.respond_to?(:+) # => false # means NilClass don't has method called :+
```

Thus `nil.+(value)` throwing a valid error. Do as below :

```
stock = {"M9788375085969"=>5, "M9788392289760"=>5, "M9788389371461"=>1, "M9788389371447"=>3, "M9788392289761"=>2}
add = {"M9788375085969"=>1, "M9788392289760"=>2, "NEW9788392289753"=>1 }

add.each do |key, value|
  p stock[key] += value if stock.has_key?(key) # it will take care of the error.
end
```

**output**

```
6
7
```

As per OP's comment I would do as :

```
add.each do |key, value|
  if stock.has_key?(key) 
     stock[key] += value 
  else
     stock[key] = value
  end
end
```

Comment: `add.each do |key, value|
  begin
    stock[key] += value
  rescue
    stock[key] = value
  end
end`

do what I needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

There is one key in your `add` hash that is missing in your `stock` hash : "NEW9788392289753".

When executing `stock["NEW9788392289753"]`, `nil` is returned, as the key is not mapped.

Answer (score 2):

because the key `NEW9788392289753` from `add` is not contained in `stock`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of treating non-existent keys is providing a default of zero:

```
stock = {"M9788375085969"=>5, "M9788392289760"=>5, "M9788389371461"=>1, "M9788389371447"=>3, "M9788392289761"=>2}
add = {"M9788375085969"=>1, "M9788392289760"=>2, "NEW9788392289753"=>1 }

stock.default = 0 

add.each do |key, value|
  stock[key] += value
end

p stock #=> {"M9788375085969"=>6, "M9788392289760"=>7, "M9788389371461"=>1, "M9788389371447"=>3, "M9788392289761"=>2, "NEW9788392289753"=>1}
```

Comment: That's also good, clean and simple solution. Ruby is beautiful and so do the Ruby community :)